# std::shared_ptr<type>(new DerivedType(...)) != std::make_shared<type>(DerivedType(...))?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, std, make-shared

I haven't found any issues quite like this yet: but if someone finds one then sorry.
I've been trying to use `std::shared_ptr` to greatly simplify memory management, however I've come across what must be some sort of bug.

When I create a `DerivedType` pointer with `std::make_shared<type>(DerivedType(...))` It can only be addressed as a `Type` rather than a `DerivedType`.

Yet when I use the syntax `std::shared_ptr<Type>(new DerivedType)` the `vfptr` table lists the correct entries and it can be cast to a `DerivedType` without a problem.

I believe there should be no difference. Is this a bug in my understanding? or an actual bug?

Thanks for your help.
Luke

Comment: Use `shared_ptr<type> p = make_shared<DerivedType>(...);` otherwise you slice the object the way you're constructing it by passing a `DerivedType` instance to the move constructor of `type`

Comment: What does "It can only be addressed as a Type rather than a DerivedType" mean?

Comment: @philipxy: It means that the object's dynamic type is `Type` not `DerivedType`. Which is to be expected, if you tell `make_shared` to make a `Type`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must pass to `std::make_shared` the parameters that you'd pass to your type's constructor, and they are *forwarded*.
You can then convert the resulting pointer to a base pointer implicitly.

```
std::shared_ptr<Type> p = std::make_shared<DerivedType>(...);
```

Let's dig a bit in the "why" in your question.

```
std::shared_ptr<Type>(new DerivedType);
```

This does work, and does nothing noteworthy. However, `std::make_shared` is usually preferred, because the latter can allocate `std::shared_ptr`'s bookkeeping data along with your object, and thus is faster and cheaper, as well as exception-safe*.

```
std::make_shared<Type>(DerivedType(...))
```

You saw it : it doesn't work. What happens here is that you create a `DerivedType` instance. `std::make_shared` happily forwards it to the constructor of `Type`.
Overload resolution happens, and `Type`'s *copy constructor* (or its move constructor, if available) is called, with a reference to your `DerivedType`'s base part. And a plain `Type` object gets instantiated and pointed to. The original `DerivedType` vanishes. This issue as a whole is called *slicing*.

*** Note on exception safety :** Shoud you use a function of the form :

```
void func(std::shared_ptr<A> a, std::shared_ptr<B> b);
```

... constructing the `std::shared_ptr`s like so :

```
func(std::shared_ptr<A>(new A), std::shared_ptr<B>(new B);
```

... can leak if, for example, `new A` is called, then `new B`, and the latter throws an exception. The `A` has not yet been wrapped into a smart pointer, and is unrecoverable.

Comment: This answer is correct but would be better if the word "slice" appeared somewhere (see @Praetorian's comment on the question). Also he is correct that in C++11 it could be the move constructor rather than the copy constructor, but that is a nitpick.

Comment: I don't really like "deprecated". It isn't deprecated in the standard, and there are actually good reasons to do the allocation separately, such as when memory is a constraint and you have `weak_ptr`s to the object that can significantly outlive the object. (Using `make_shared` in that scenario means that the memory cannot be freed until all `weak_ptr`s are gone.) It's also perfectly exception-safe; if the `shared_ptr` constructor throws an exception, the pointer is guaranteed deleted.

Comment: @T.C. Yes, I thought so. I'd welcome a better term/expression, because I don't know one ! Also, I'll add some more on exception safety.

Comment: I'd just say something like "usually `make_shared` is preferred"

Comment: @T.C. thank you ! Also, if you're now worried about exception-safety, the way to go is `std::shared_ptr<A>(std::make_unique<A>(...))` :)

Comment: @Quentin Yep. I wasn't thinking about the two `shared_ptr`s scenario when I wrote my first comment :)

Comment: Thanks, it never would have occurred to me that calling `std::make_shared<Type>(DerivedType(...)` would end up calling the copy (or move) constructor of the base class rather than just creating an instance and using that. Hence it was my understanding that was wrong.

Answer (score -3):

```
std::make_shared<type>(DerivedType(...))
```

HEre replace `make_shared<Type>` with `make_shared<DerivedType>` and it all should work

upd: highlighted the change

Comment: Because although this will work, it's still using `make_shared` incorrectly. The point of `make_shared` is it constructs the object, so constructing an object to pass to `make_shared` is redundant and less efficient, and won't compile for non-copyable types.